# Why images from storage directory are not being displayed in view? Laravel

Tags: laravel, path, storage

In my app, I want to upload images in `storage` directory and display them in the `view`, storing images in `storage` directory has been successful so far, but I can't display them in the view! I think I might be specifying the path in the wrong way, but can't find the right way! I am using `storage:link` artisan command.

My store method:

```
public function store (Request $request) {

    $inputs = $request->validate([
        'post_image' => 'image',
    ]);

    if ($request->post_image) {
        $inputs['post_image'] = $request->post_image->store('images', 'public');
    }

    Auth()->user()->post()->create($inputs);
}
```

My Attribute Accessor for uploaded images' paths:

```
   protected function postImage(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: function ($value) {
            if (str_contains($value, 'https://') || str_contains($value, 'http://')) {
                return $value;
            }
            return asset('storage/' . $value);
        }
    );
}
```

In my filesystem.php :

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],
```

And in my .env:

```
FILESYSTEM_DISK=public
```

This is the final `src` I get for the `img` in the view following this way:

```
src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/lxDQfi7COYHmW6SmYY2RxFUmpoajoKo0sqTcJ6ux.jpg"
```

Can somebody please tell my where is my mistake in specifying the right way of displaying the image (path) ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this method to save the photo on public folder

```
$image = $request->file('image');
$new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
```